# 3d модели на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, 3d

Добрый вечер. Делаю сайт оружейной энциклопедии. Хотелось бы загружать на страницу 3D модели оружия с возможностью крутить их. Модели буду брать из интернета. Подскажите в каком направлении двигаться? Что почитать, может есть какие-то сервисы, которые позволяют быстро встроить эти модели?

Comment: canvas, webGL...

Comment: Очень советую библиотеку **Three.js** . Там уже реализованы загрузчики 3D моделей, если не найдёте нужный, можете написать свой

Answer (score 2):

[Blend4Web](https://www.blend4web.com/ru/) - Редактор на основе [Blender](https://blender.org/).

Есть возможность сделать простую крутилку, есть возможность навешать логику, как кодом, так и через визуальный редактор. Загружаем модель в Blender, настраиваем материалы и экспортируем в html или специальный веб-плеер.

[Sketchfab](https://sketchfab.com/) - Сервис по хостингу 3Д моделей.

В виде плагина для множества 3Д-программ. Есть возможность сделать крутилку и анимацию, логики нет, но вам и не надо. Модель загружается на Sketchfab как на Youtube.